# Why can't I access my angular2 class property

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm new to Angular 2 and thoroughly puzzled at this moment.

I am loading a component which retrieves data from service (in JSON format), and I am apparently NOT being successful when it comes to setting a property in my class which I want to represent that data.

I can however (with debugger) see the returned data and `alert()` it. I think that I am setting the property, but the template reports an error that it does not understand the property.

So, I have this:

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { SiteService } from './site.service';
import { Site } from './site';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'site-detail',
    templateUrl: 'site-detail.component.html'
})
export class SiteDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    public site: Site;  // **Site is an interface**

    constructor(
        private siteService: SiteService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location
    ) { }

    // getSite(): void {
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params
            .switchMap((params: Params) => this.siteService.getSite(params['id']))
            .subscribe((data: Response) => {
                this.site = data[0];
                alert(this.site.sitex_invoiceAccount); ** ALL LOOKS GOOD AT THIS POINT **
            })
    }
}
```

The `alert()` happily reports the correct `invoiceAccount` value, suggesting to me that I have assigned the data to my property `site`.

However, the template is not convinced and this snippet:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="xxxx">Site ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="site.sitex_invoiceAccount">
 </div>
```

tells me:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/site-detail.component.html:5:52 caused by: Cannot read property 'sitex_invoiceAccount' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'sitex_invoiceAccount' of undefined

Can anyone to tell me the error that I am committing please?

Thank you kind people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are getting data using HTTP call which is an asynchronous operation and you are trying to display data before you get it from server. Basically, before your `site` variable is filled with data you get from HTTP call, it is `undefined` and that's why you are getting this error. You can use safe navigation operator (`?`) in your template to protect it until data arrive:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="xxxx">Site ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="site?.sitex_invoiceAccount">
</div>
```

You can also use `NgIf` directive to render that part of your template only after you populate `sata` variable with data:

```
<div *ngIf="site" class="form-group">
    <label for="xxxx">Site ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="site.sitex_invoiceAccount">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, what a basic mistake to make! Thanks, I guess that I assumed that the template would render **after** the ngOnInit - I obviously need to read up on the lifecycle. 

Thanks, I will try those changes now.

Comment: Result! Thank you very much Stefan.

Answer (score 2):

Try to initialize the this.site property earlier, for example in constructor like:

```
this.site = {}
```

The problem is, that in time of evaluation of `site.sitex_invoiceAccount` in your template, `site` is really `undefined`. It happens earlier, then your subscribe method finishes.

Comment: Thank you Petr, I will do that.

Comment: I had to use: `this.site = <Site>{};`